# Unable to load table data in the webpage through selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

I am trying to open the URL and then change select option to 3(index) to popup data on the table of the webpage based on option 3 and click on 4 th column table header of table to sort it out and then extract top 4 rows into my java program .Webpage is opening in chrome but data is not displayed for default select option. Is there anything wrong with my program or its this particular URL. Here is my code:

```
public class FirstSeleniumTest {
    WebDriver driver;
    
    public void launchBrowser(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Aghahussain\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/pre-open-market-cm-and-emerge-market");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);

        //Select dropdown=new Select(driver.findElement(By.className("no-border-radius")));
        //WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"select-pre\"]/select/option[4]"));
        //dropdown.selectByIndex(3);
        //System.out.print(ele.getText());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FirstSeleniumTest ft=new FirstSeleniumTest();
        ft.launchBrowser();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no [records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u63pZ.png) for this particular option confirm with dev team whether this value has no data or it is an issue

Comment: @MohamedSulaimaanSheriff here is my question updated in a better way to understand, If you have a look please, any help is appreciated. Thank you.   https://stackoverflow.com/q/63420617/13557071