# Unable to run javaScript on change Function though Web Scraping Using Selenium With Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

My task:

1)I have to go this url :   https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/pre_open_market/pre_open_market.htm

2)Select the option "FO Stocks" from selection box so that New table of FO Stocks will appear.

3)After that Sort the table in decending by click on "FFM Column" which has href table header.

Extract Top 5 Rows of the Table.

My Approach:

Selenium Webdriver using Java

1)I have sucessfully opened the url in FireFox tried with Chrome which is talking to long to load the whole page.

2)After Loading of webpage I changed the Selection Box Value to FO by using ID of select box and value of Option. the following code Snippet shows this.

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("selId")));
dropdown.selectByValue("fo");
```

Problem: The table doesn't update value according to the selected option might be because `onchange()` function of javascript doesn't execute/enabled after changing value of selection box on that page.

3)How to click on this Column using Selenium Webdriver (Any tips is Appreciated).

Here is the Code

```
public class FirstSeleniumTest {
WebDriver driver;
public void waitForLoad(WebDriver driver) {
System.out.print("waiting for javascript sucessfully");
new WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) wd ->
((JavascriptExecutor) wd).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
}
public void launchBrowser() {
// System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
// driver = new ChromeDriver();
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities dcap = new DesiredCapabilities();
dcap.setCapability("pageLoadStrategy", "eager");
FirefoxOptions opt=new FirefoxOptions();
opt.merge(dcap);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(opt);
System.out.print("Driver loaded sucessfully");
     driver.get("https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/pre_open_market/pre_open_market.htm");
waitForLoad(driver);
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("selId")));
waitForLoad(driver);
dropdown.selectByValue("fo");
waitForLoad(driver);
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
FirstSeleniumTest ft=new FirstSeleniumTest();
ft.launchBrowser();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting, trying removing the attribute of the first element and add "selected" attribute to the option you want to select through jquery/javascript. After that trigger the  element's on change method.

Comment: i cant remove the element or deselect the default selected option I am gettin an error, and sometimes it doesn't load the table data for default selected option.

Answer (score 0):

Try triggering that with:

```
$('selId').trigger('change')
```

Comment: I added this line but nothing triggers no error ,still table data doesn't load

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the below steps which have worked for me**

1. Launch the chrome manually from custom user directory as shown in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp9I1.png)

   1. Go to chrome browser exe path
      in windows will be like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\`
   2. Open CMD in this path and execute the below command
      `chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:\selenum\AutomationProfile"`  where `C:\selenum\AutomationProfile` is custom user data directory
   3. Now launch manually your [URL](https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/pre_open_market/pre_open_market.htm) which is to be automated in this browser
   4. Wait until webpage loads completely and close the browser
2. Now from selenium launch the browser from this custom `user-data-dir` using the code below

```java
public class Test {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Your Driver path");
        ChromeOptions option=new ChromeOptions();
        //arguments to launch chrome with Custom user dir path
        option.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\selenum\\AutomationProfile\\");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
        
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/pre_open_market/pre_open_market.htm"); // WebElement
        Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("selId")));
        dropdown.selectByValue("fo");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        dropdown.selectByValue("sme");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        dropdown.selectByValue("niftybank");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        
    }

}
```

Handle dropdowns with required webdriver wait to **scrape** the table data and using `Thread.sleep` is not recommended one.

Reason behind launching chrome in custom user profile is to ensure fast website loading in chrome and also website is blocking the client browser when it is launched from selenium that's the reason it takes time to load in chrome automated browser and no data change based on the dropdown values

Hope this will be helpful

Comment: Bro Thank you soooo much ,I followed what you said and it works like a charm. :) Thank you once again for helping a newbie. I appreciate it.

Comment: @syedasgar Kindly upvote or mark the [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354584/teaching-new-users-how-to-accept-an-answer) as accepted if it is useful by clicking on the check mark or up arrow near the answer